# Can I use a heart monitor overnight to determine my resting heart rate?

Tags: heart-rate-monitor, heart

Last night I wore my heart rate monitor while sleeping to determine what my resting heart rate was.  This morning I checked and the lowest my heart was beating was 48 bpm and the max was 100 bpm, the average was 65 bpm.

So is 48 bpm a valid resting heart rate, or does my resting heart rate have to be checked while I'm conscious?

Update: Redid the test but after waking up and got a 54 bpm while I was awake.

Comment: It could be quite uncomfortable if you toss and turn, so wearing it while sleeping is something only some people could do.

Comment: @RobinAshe Agreed, had to take the watch off early this morning. But from what I have been reading you need to take your RHR first thing in the morning and unless I wake up super slow without an alarm, it's hard to get anything below 80 bpm and I'm an active individual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, it's a valid resting HR, but I don't think it's what you want. It is going to be different than a resting HR taken while you're awake, which is the generally accepted usable number. Other than academic interest or determining disease patterns (Generally done with a Holter monitor), I can't think of anything that uses a sleeping RHR as a base.